# How to implement button_click event without clicking button

Tags: c#

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Dosomething();
}

private void Something(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSend_click( how to write in here?? )
}
```

I want to implement `btnSend_Click` in other section(?), but i don't know how to do this. i want to implement this code without using UI.

Comment: [`Button.PerformClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.button.performclick?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to call the method `btnSend_Click` from the method `Something`, you can pick any of these:

```
private void Something(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSend_click(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Or

```
private void Something(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSend_click(sender, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is all about naming, that is, giving the methods a good name.

First, you write the underlying method that *does the actual work*.

```
public class Someone 
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.Beep(); //make a noise
    }
}
```

At this point, no UI is involved, no button, no `sender`, no `EventArgs`.

Then

Call this method when the button is clicked.

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Someone().DoSomething();
}
```

Call this method from any other place.

```
class AnotherOne 
{
    private void DoAnotherThing()
    {
        new Someone().DoSomething();     
    }
}
```

I don't answer your question on how to call `btnSend_click` from anywhere by passing **faked** `sender` and `EventArgs`.

Because that is not a good idea to write such calls - before long you will be confused by the names even if the code was written by yourself.